# SQL syntax error when using inner joins in query

Tags: mysql

Working query

```
(   SELECT R.ref as ref, 
           R.field8, 
           R.file_extension, 
           DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, 
           Ra.rank as rank 
    FROM resource R 
    INNER  JOIN resource_ranking Ra ON R.ref = Ra.ref_id 
    ORDER BY Ra.rank limit 2
) 
UNION ALL
(   SELECT R.ref as ref, 
           R.field8, 
           R.file_extension, 
           DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, 
           '99' as rank  
    FROM resource R
    LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT ref_id 
           FROM resource_ranking 
           ORDER BY rank LIMIT 2
    ) AS B ON R.ref = B.ref_id
    INNER JOIN collection_resource C ON R.ref = C.resource
    WHERE B.ref_id IS NULL 
      AND R.ref !=  '-1' AND C.collection = 1 
)
ORDER BY rank ASC, ref DESC LIMIT 0,  8
```

the above query is working fine i wants to add another table to existing query using inner joins

Below is my written query using inner joins

```
(   SELECT R.ref as ref, 
           R.field8, 
           R.file_extension, 
           DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, 
           Ra.rank as rank 
    FROM resource R 
    INNER  JOIN resource_ranking Ra ON R.ref = Ra.ref_id 
    ORDER BY Ra.rank limit 2
    INNER  JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id 
    ORDER BY Rr.rating DESC
) 
UNION ALL
(   SELECT R.ref as ref, 
           R.field8, 
           R.file_extension, 
           DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, 
           '99' as rank  
    FROM resource R
    LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT ref_id 
         FROM resource_ranking 
         ORDER BY rank LIMIT 2
    ) AS B ON R.ref = B.ref_id
    INNER JOIN collection_resource C ON R.ref = C.resource
    WHERE B.ref_id IS NULL AND Rr.userid=1 
      AND R.ref !=  '-1' AND C.collection = 1
)
ORDER BY rank ASC, ref DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id ORDER BY Rr.rating DESC' at line 3
```

Comment: So what's going wrong? No rows? Too many rows? Error in SQL?

Comment: syntax error at  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id ORDER BY Rr.rating DESC' at line 3

Comment: Ok - I've added that to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try after getting rid of this:

```
 ORDER BY Ra.rank limit 2
```

If you only want two rows from the joins place the LIMIT 2 after the second one.

Comment: I got my query working perfectly here is my query after your guidance:

Comment: Ok, and finally i want  to add "ORDER BY Rr.rating DESC" for this query how can i adapt.

Answer (score 1):

This is your first subquery:

```
SELECT R.ref as ref, R.field8, R.file_extension,
       DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, Ra.rank as rank
FROM resource R  INNER JOIN
     resource_ranking Ra
     ON R.ref = Ra.ref_id
ORDER BY Ra.rank
limit 2
INNER  JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id ORDER BY Rr.rating DESC)
```

The `inner join` is in the wrong place.  Try this:

```
SELECT R.ref as ref, R.field8, R.file_extension,
       DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, Ra.rank as rank
FROM resource R  INNER JOIN
     resource_ranking Ra
     ON R.ref = Ra.ref_id INNER JOIN
     resource_rating Rr
     ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id
ORDER BY Ra.rank
limit 2
```

I'm not sure what the additional `order by` clause is for.

If you learn to format your queries so they are readable, it will be easier for you to find syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
INNER  JOIN resource_ranking Ra ON R.ref = Ra.ref_id 
ORDER BY Ra.rank limit 2
INNER  JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id 
ORDER BY Rr.rating DESC
```

The SELECT statement can have only one ORDER BY clause, and it must be the last clause in the statement (ORDER BY must be at the end):

```
SELECT ....
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON ....
JOIN ......
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT R.ref as ref, R.field8, R.file_extension, Rr.rating, DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, Ra.rank as rank FROM resource R 
    INNER  JOIN resource_ranking Ra ON R.ref = Ra.ref_id 
    INNER JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id
ORDER BY Ra.rank limit 2) 
UNION ALL
    (SELECT R.ref as ref, R.field8, R.file_extension, Rr.rating, DATE_FORMAT(R.creation_date,'%e/%c/%Y') as date, '99' as rank  FROM resource R
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ref_id FROM resource_ranking ORDER BY rank LIMIT 2) AS B ON R.ref = B.ref_id
    INNER JOIN collection_resource C ON R.ref = C.resource
    INNER JOIN resource_rating Rr ON R.ref = Rr.resource_id
    WHERE B.ref_id IS NULL AND Rr.user_id = 1 
    AND R.ref !=  '-1' AND C.collection = 1)
    ORDER BY rank ASC, ref DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```